# Execute loop n times with a sleep delay

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The API I'm calling has a rate limit of 200 requests per min. I have ~1,500 (conversation) threads I'm trying to initially pull, so trying to iterate through the loop 150 times and then sleep it for 90 seconds.

This loop is used in create a CSV file:

```
conversations.each do |conversation|
    customer = conversation.customer
    threaded_conversation = helpscout.conversation(conversation.id)
    sleep(0.4)
end
```

I've tried to use `times` but I feel like there is a better solution that I'm not aware of.

```
150.times do
   # above loop
end
```

Comment: Why do you get that feeling? If you have a specific number of iterations, `times` is exactly the right thing to use.

Comment: _"trying to iterate through the loop 150 times"_ – you probably don't want to pull all 1,500 threads 150 times, so what does that mean? Do you want to process batches of 150 items or maybe 10 items (1,500 / 150)?

Comment: _" a rate limit of 200 requests per min"_ – why do you want to sleep fo 90 seconds after 150 iterations instead of 60 seconds per 200 iterations? And what is that `sleep(0.4)`?

Comment: @Stefan In case actually support tickets are also counted towards that limit, and would prevent someone submitting something while I'll pulling results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep track of the iterations count and then sleep if it's a multiple of 150:

```
conversations.each.with_index do |conversation, index|
    customer = conversation.customer
    threaded_conversation = helpscout.conversation(conversation.id)
    if index % 150 == 0
      sleep 90
    end
end
```